# A Java Matlab/Julia Interface

Tags: java, matlab, julia, bufferedreader

In the Matlab code below I use Java to create a command-line interface to the external Julia program.
Working in principle, I can experience (timing?) problems where the output is garbled, not complete, or delayed.

Are there better methods, how to assure the completion of the external program?

```
function obj = JuliaServer

% Use:
% jl = JuliaServer
% jl.start()
% jl.call('cos.(randn(3,3))')
% ...
% jl.stop()

import java.io.*
import java.net.*

%% properties

in = 0;
out = 0;
err = 0;

%% public methods

obj.start = @start;
obj.call = @call;
obj.stop = @stop;

%% methods

    function start
        rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
        pr = rt.exec('julia -iq');
        in = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        out = PrintWriter(pr.getOutputStream());
        err = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
    end

    function [res, errmsg] = call(cmd)
        println(out, cmd);
        flush(out);
        while ~(ready(in) || ready(err)), end
        res = '';
        while (ready(in))
            res = append(res, sprintf('%s\n', strtrim(char(readLine(in)))));
        end
        errmsg = '';
        if ready(err)
            errmsg = sprintf('cmd: ''%s''\n', cmd);
            while (ready(err))
                errmsg = append(errmsg, sprintf('%s\n', strtrim(char(readLine(err)))));
            end
            error(errmsg)
        end
    end

    function stop
        println(out, 'exit()');
        out.flush();
    end

end
```

Comment: Calling Matlab directly from Julia works really well via Matlab.jl. Would that work for you? And calling Julia from Matlab is also possible via Mex.jl https://github.com/jebej/Mex.jl/.

Comment: In some applications, I have to call Julia from Matlab because of existing frameworks. Julia then could replace the work-intensive Mex files. I had no luck getting Mex.jl (and others using the API) to work. The discourse postings and issue trackers give the impression that an interface has changed. These posts are already a couple of years old. Please let me know if you are more successful! - Thats why I choose the (stable) command-line interface. The bulk of IO is then done via files, pipes, sockets or memory maps.  The CLI is merely used to signal function call completion.

Comment: The call() stops updating at the first false in.ready(), which could happen well before the completion of the external program. Potential fix could be (1) keep updating until a keyword returns (2) keep updating until multiple false in.ready() accumulation (e.g. for 500 ms)

Comment: Yes, the keyword solution appears the most stable.

Answer (score 1):

The call() function in this script stops updating at the first false in.ready(), which could happen well before the completion of the external program. Potential fix could be (1) keep updating until a keyword returns (2) keep updating until multiple false in.ready() accumulation (e.g. for 500 ms).